# Get JSON value from second level in array's hierarchy using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, hierarchical-data

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "stars":5,
  "numberOfReviews":{
    "total":1179,
  }
}
```

and the following PHP:

```
$json = file_get_contents('url-of-json');
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->stars;
```

This prints `5` as expected. How do I print the "total" value of `1179` from the second level in the array's hierarchy?

I've been unable to find an explanation on how to achieve this. Here's some example of what I've been trying so far:

```
print $obj->total
print $obj->{'numberOfReviews', 'total'}
print $obj->['numberOfReviews']['total']
print $obj->numberOfReviews{'total'}
print $obj->[1]['total']
print $obj->numberOfReviews[0]total
print $obj->total[1]
```

Comment: I think you've over-thinking this, possibly because you're looking for how to extract information from an array. This is simply two nested objects, so the syntax you need is just `$obj->numberOfReviews->total`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: One thing is that the JSON isn't valid, need to remove the comma at the end of `"total":1179,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$obj->numberOfReviews` is an \stdClass object too, so try it with `$obj->numberOfReviews->total`

Answer (score 1):

$obj->numberOfReviews->total;
Or add second parameter to json_decode with true value, and use it as array.